# Pass return value of 'before_action' to coming actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

This is my MpdController:

```
class MpdController < ApplicationController
  require 'ruby-mpd'

  def status
    mpd = MPD.new
    mpd.connect
    # ... 
    mpd.disconnect
  end

  def help
    mpd = MPD.new
    mpd.connect
    # ... 
    mpd.disconnect
  end

  def pause
    mpd = MPD.new
    mpd.connect
    # ... 
    mpd.disconnect
  end
end
```

As you can see, each and every of the methods requires a new instance of MPD and saves it into my variable.
Now, would it be possible to do that via before_action and after_action, provided by Rails?

I thought about something like:

```
before_action :new_mpd
after_action :disconnect_mpd

def new_mpd
    mpd = MPD.new
    mpd.connect
    mpd
end

def disconnect_mpd(mpd)
    mpd.disconnect
end
```

It would require to get the return value from my before-filter and pass it then further to my after-filter.

Is this something that works?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done by assigning to controller instance variables.

```
before_action :new_mpd

def status
  # use @mpd
end

private

def new_mpd
  @mpd = MPD.new
  @mpd.connect
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working like a charm! Gonna accept your answer in 6 minutes :)

Comment: Just to provide a bit of explanation - `mpd`, rather than `@mpd`, is a `local variable`, which means it's only defined within the context of the block or method in which it's created, which in this case is the `new_mpd` method.

Comment: @MaxWilliams: yeah, sometimes I forget this is not obvious :)